# Vue 2 Laravel 5.3 Infinte Update Loop

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

There is no console log error but anything that I put in `updated()` hook [in the current code `getCartItems/`] will be rendered infinitely for some reasons that I do not know. even I set it as `alert('hi')` and it alert it infinitely. So I suspect something makes the project keeps updating values or something but I do not know where. Can anyone give me a suggestion to check where the problem is?

Cart-dropdown.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row cart-dropdown-row" v-for="cart in carts">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="cart-dropdown-img-wrapper">
                    <img class="d-flex align-self-center cart-dropdown-img" :src="cart.product_choice.img1" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 cart-dropdown-info-wrapper">
                <h6 class="cart-dropdown-info">{{cart.product.name}}</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 cart-dropdown-qty-wrapper">
                <div class="cart-dropdown-qty">x{{cart.qty}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>
      <div class="row cart-dropdown-checkout-wrapper">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm cart-dropdown-checkout" @click.prevent="goCheckout()">Check Out</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        carts:{},
      }
    },
    props:[
    ],
    mounted(){
      this.getCartItems()
    },
    updated(){
      this.getCartItems()
    },
    methods:{
        getCartItems(){
            var vm = this
        vm.$http.get('/getCartItems/').then((response)=>{
          vm.carts = response.data
        });
        },
        goCheckout(){
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/cart'
        }
    },
    computed:{
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `getCartItems` from both `computed` and `updated` hook?

Comment: you mean 'mounted' I would say. the one in 'mounted' is trying to get the initial cart items. the one in 'updated' is to get the updated items if the 'cart' data is changed somewhere in the project (such as quantity)

Comment: Yes, I meant `mounted`, you probably have to find some other strategy or use two way binding of vue to change the data as well.

Comment: understood, I might dig into it a little bit more. Thank you for answering my question as usual

Comment: @Saurabh Im thinking how should i do it and I try `mounted(){ CartEvent.$on('carts', function (carts){ vm.carts = carts }) }`  but this is not executed automatically upon `CartEvent.$emit` Any ideas? where should I put `CartEvent.$on('carts',...)` so that it does execute "on" `carts` change in some other component?

Comment: As it says [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) `CartEvent.$on` have to be inside created hook.

Comment: OMG now I see it. that tiny word // in the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the vue instance data variable `carts` in the updated hooks and as [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) says: updated hook is **called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.** So you are in a infinite loop: you change the vue data it updates the the DOM and call the updated block which again change the data.

This is also mention in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated):

> you can perform DOM-dependent operations in this hook. However, in most cases you should avoid changing state in this hook, **because it may lead to an infinite update loop.**

You can see this circle in the below vue instance lifecycle diagram.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that when I use the update() hook I should never try to set values/variables?

Comment: Yes: one should perform DOM-dependent operations in this hook. However, in most cases you should avoid changing state in this hook, because it may lead to an infinite update loop.

Comment: if that is the case, what would you suggest me if I want to have the cart value updated upon cart database updated?